# notation 3 URI to RDF/XML

Tags: uri, converters, rdf, n3, n-triples

I'm trying to convert an n3 file to rdf/xml through rdf:about converter. Unfortunately some URIs have special characters like:
    . -> gene:01.01.01
    % -> gene:fog2/zfpm2
    | -> gene:17867|203045

and the convertor note this examples as a notation 3 grammar error. I searched everywhere for escaping characters which would help me make the convention but with no success.
Does anyone know how i could represent these special characters in the URIs? is there any other convertor that would allow me proceed this convention?

if i remove these URIs, my file is converted normally. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable thing will be to write out the URIs in full. So if you have:

```
@prefix gene: <http://example.com/>

gene:fog2/zfpm rdfs:label "something".
```

rewrite this instead to:

```
@prefix gene: <http://example.com/>

<http://example.com/fog2/zfpm> rdfs:label "something".
```

Note, some characters are not even allowed in this notation (for example, spaces). In that case, they need to be handled with [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

```
<http://example.com/fog2/zfpm%20xyz> rdfs:label "something".
```

Here the space has been percent-encoded as `%20`.

The latest [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) spec (Turtle is W3C's standardized version of the non-standard N3) also allows escaping of *some* of these special characters as backslashes:

```
gene:fog2\/zfpm rdfs:label "something".
```

But this isn't widely implemented yet, and older tools/services won't support it. The rdfabout.com converter certainly won't support it.

[triplr.org](http://triplr.org/) is better than rdfabout.com, by the way.

Comment: Thanks cygri for your reply. So if I get it right, the only way to get through this is to use the full URI instead of the sorter ones.

Comment: I found this latest turtle spec but i didn't find any converter that can accept such a syntax.

Comment: The latest Apache Jena probably handles the newest Turtle correctly, if you use the RIOT parsers. If you're looking for a simple online converter, you're probably out of luck. The backslash escaping was added very recently.